# sqoop create impala parquet table

Tags: bash, hadoop, sqoop, impala, parquet

I'm relatively new the process of sqooping so pardon any ignorance. I have been trying to sqoop a table from a data source as a parquet file and create an impala table (also as parquet) into which I will insert the sqooped data. The code runs without an issue, but when I try to select a couple rows for testing I get the error:

```
.../EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM_SQOOP/ec2fe2b0-c9fa-4ef9-91f8-46cf0e12e272.parquet' has an incompatible Parquet schema for column 'dru_id.test_ewt_call_prof_dim_parquet.call_prof_sk_id'. Column type: INT, Parquet schema: optional byte_array CALL_PROF_SK_ID [i:0 d:1 r:0]
```

I was mirroring the process I found on a cloudera guide here:https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_create_table.html. Mainly the "Internal and External Tables" section. I've been trying to avoid having to infer the schema with a particular parquet file, since this whole thing will be kicked off every month with a bash script (and I also can't think of a way to point it to just one file if I use more than one mapper).

Here's the code I used. I feel like I'm either missing something small and stupid, or I've screwed up everything major without realizing it. Any and all help appreciated. thanks!

```
    sqoop import -Doraoop.import.hint=" " \
    --options-file /home/kemri/pass.txt \
    --verbose \
    --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid:389/cn=OracleContext,dc=[employer],dc=com/EWSOP000 \
    --username [userid] \
    --num-mappers 1 \
    --target-dir hdfs://nameservice1/data/res/warehouse/finance/[dru_userid]/EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM_SQOOP \
    --delete-target-dir \
    --table DMPROD.EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM \
    --direct \
    --null-string '\\N' \
    --null-non-string '\\N' \
    --as-parquetfile 


impala-shell -k -i hrtimpslb.[employer].com


create external table test_EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM_parquet(
CALL_PROF_SK_ID INT,
SRC_SKL_CD_ID STRING,
SPLIT_NM STRING,
SPLIT_DESC STRING,
CLM_SYS_CD STRING,
CLM_SYS_NM STRING,
LOB_CD STRING,
LOB_NM STRING,
CAT_IND STRING,
CALL_TY_CD STRING,
CALL_TY_NM STRING,
CALL_DIR_CD STRING,
CALL_DIR_NM STRING,
LANG_CD STRING,
LANG_NM STRING,
K71_ATOMIC_TS TIMESTAMP)
stored as parquet location '/data/res/warehouse/finance/[dru_userid]/EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM_SQOOP';
```

Comment: You could also consider using the option `--hive-import` which immediately creates hive tables with underlying parquet files without you having to worry. Impala uses the same table metastore so no issues there.

Comment: @spijs thanks for the suggestion! Would this automatically exist in Impala once sqooped or would I have to go into Hue > Impala and refresh the metastore? Any amount of manual steps are a no go since we're creating this for business partners.

Comment: You woud indeed have to refresh the meta store. You will also need the tablename to create the table so adding an impala command to your script is probably less work than for example defining all your columns which is not necessary with - -hive-import

Comment: @spijs okay, that's what I thought. If I'm not mistaken, creating an impala table right off the bat would eliminate needing to refresh anything (unless the refresh can be performed in the bash script)

Comment: @spijs I've spent some time searching for examples of --hive -import jobs, but can't find much. Would you be able to show me on my code about how to facilitate that? much appreciated!

Comment: Added this as an answer due to limited space here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request in the comments I provide an example of how you could achieve the same using one sqoop import with `--hive-import`. For obvious reasons I haven't tested it for your specific requirements, so it could need some more tuning which is often the case with these sqoop commands.
In my experience importing as parquet forces you to use the `--query` option since it doesn't allow you to use schema.table as table.

```
sqoop import -Doraoop.import.hint=" "\
--verbose \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://oid:389/cn=OracleContext,dc=[employer],dc=com/EWSOP000 \
--username [userid] \
-m 1 \
--password [ifNecessary] \
--hive-import \
--query 'SELECT * FROM DMPROD.EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM WHERE $CONDITIONS' \
--hive-database [database you want to use] \
--hive-table test_EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM_parquet \
--target-dir hdfs://nameservice1/data/res/warehouse/finance/[dru_userid]/EWT_CALL_PROF_DIM_SQOOP \
--null-string '\\N' \
--null-non-string '\\N' \
--as-parquetfile
```

Basically what you need for `--hive-import` is `--hive-database`, `--hive-table` and `--query`. 
If you don't want all your columns to appear in Hive as strings you must also include:

```
--map-hive-columns [column_name1=Timestamp,column_name2=Int,...]
```

You might need a similar `--map-java-columns` as well, but I'm never sure when this is required.
You will need a `--split-by` if you want multiple mappers

As discussed in the comments you will need to use `invalidate metadata db.table` to make sure Impala sees these changes. You could issue both commands from CL or a single bash-script where you can issue the impala command using `impala-shell -q [query]`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and the walkthrough! I will be testing this as soon as I possibly can today.

Comment: for the --hive-database parameter, when you say "database you want to use", does this mean the name of the oracle db we're trying to sqoop from or something else?

Comment: The name of the hive metastore database . not the source db

Comment: pardon the ignorance, but how do I know what the metastore db name is?

Comment: Also, does this --hive-database table need to already exist, have a schema, etc? or is it possible to create it in the process or create an empty "shell", if you will, to point the sqoop to?

Comment: If you don't know the database name it probably is 'default'. The Hive-import will automatically  create the table schema which you can change with map-hive-columns

Comment: thank you very, very much for all of your help thus far! everything appears to be working except that I apparently don't have privileges for CREATETABE. I'll have to find a workaround or get the permissions I guess.

Comment: This might also have something to do with the database you are writing to. If you are given your own db chances are you cant write to default

Comment: Okay, using my dru_[user_id] db worked! everything runs and is in my HIVE directory. so how do I use the invalidate metadata db.table code to force impala to see that I created this table?

Comment: Run `invalidate metadata [hive_database].[hive_table` either in the Hue impala editor or CLI. or just run `impala-shell -q "invalidate metadata [hive_database].[hive_table]"` from command-line

Comment: that worked! thank you very much all the priceless help!