# Questions about Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, sqoop

I have this environment:

- Haddop environment (1 master, 4 slaves) with several applications:
  ambari, hue, hive, sqoop, hdfs ... Server in production (separate
  from hadoop) with mysql database.

My goal is:

- Optimize the queries made on this mysql server that are slow to
  execute today.

What did I do:

- I imported the mysql data to HDFS using Sqoop.

My doubts:

1. I can not make selects direct in HDFS using Hive?
2. Do I have to load the data into Hive and make the queries?
3. If new data is entered into the mysql database, what is the best way
   to get this data and insert it into HDFS and then insert it into
   Hive again? (Maybe in real time)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can not make selects direct in HDFS using Hive?

You can. Create [**External Table**](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-ExternalTables) in hive specifying your hdfs location. Then you can perform any HQL over it.

> Do I have to load the data into Hive and make the queries?

In case of external table, you don't need to load data in hive; your data resides in the same HDFS directory.

> If new data is entered into the mysql database, what is the best way to get this data.

You can use Sqoop [**Incremental Import**](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports) for this. It will fetch only newly added/updated data (*depending upon incremental mode*). You can create a [**sqoop job**](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_literal_sqoop_job_literal) and schedule it as per your need.

Comment: Instead of #1 and #2 you could also try to sqoop data using `--hive-import`. Your data will immediately be usable with Hive and Impala. More information for OP on bringing in data in one step and being able to query it with the faster Impala [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42116606/sqoop-create-impala-parquet-table/42130964#42130964). The answer brings in data in the generally faster parquet format.

Comment: Thank you for your attention!

Comment: @sola.carol happy to help !

Answer (score 1):

You can try **Impala** which is much faster than Hive in case of SQL queries. You need to define tables most probably specifying some delimiter, storage format and where the data is stored on HDFS (I don't know what kind of data are you storing). Then you can write SQL queries which will take the data from HDFS.

I have no experience with real-time data ingestion from relational databases, however you can try scheduling Sqoop jobs with cron.

Comment: Thank you for your attention!